# Like operator in LINQ to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, linq, wcf

how to use like in linq for mysql. please see my code below. the parameter productname is giving the input value. but when i run this query, result is not coming. how to do this with mysql provider

```
    public List<Product> GetProductsByProductName(string storeId, string productName)
    {
        Authenticate();
        int _storeId = Convert.ToInt32(storeId);
        var _products = (from p in context.products.AsEnumerable()
                         where p.StoreId == _storeId && p.ProductName.Contains(productName) && p.ProductIsAvailable.Equals(true)
                         orderby p.ProductName
                         select
                             new Product()
                             {
                                 ProductName = p.ProductName,
                                 CategoryID = p.CategoryId,
                                 QuantityPerUnit = p.ProductUnit,
                                 UnitPrice = p.ProductPrice,
                                 DiscountValue = p.DiscountValue,
                                 DiscountType = p.DiscountType,
                                 ProductDescription = p.ProductDescription,
                                 ProductURL = p.ProductURL,
                                 ProductSmallDescription = p.ProductSmallDescription,
                                 ProductListPrice = p.ProductListPrice

                             }).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: could you please post your error, please check within inner exception what error are coming

Comment: i am not getting any error. data is not retrieving from db.

Comment: You aren't using LINQ to MySQL. That `AsEnumerable` line loads *all products* in memory and the rest of the query just uses LINQ to Objects

Comment: Assuming you mean LinqConnect ( the new name of the LINQ to MySQL product by Devart), simply remove `AsEnumerable()`. LinqConnect supports case-insensitive queries with `Contains` [since 2010](http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=14937). Whether `Contains` maps to a case-sensitive or insensitive clause depends on the database's settings

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here it is.... if it is MySQL we need to use .ToLower(). please see the code below.

p.ProductName.ToLower().Contains(productName.ToLower())

thank you...

Comment: Your code isn't using LINQ to access the database otherwise `ToLower()` wouldn't work. `AsEnumerable()` causes all products to be loaded in memory. Anyway, Contains would be equivalent to `LIKE '%something%'`. `StartsWith`, `EndsWith` would be equivalent to `xxx%`, `%xxx`

Comment: Since you are using LINQ to Objects, instead of `String.Contains` you can use the [String.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that accepts a [StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx) parameter to make a case-insensitive search